# Boolean Trouble with If statement VBA Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I am confused on the conditional operators of VBA.  It probably has something to do with weird type casting, but I am stuck and need some help -

```
query = "SELECT * FROM [records_table] " & _
    "WHERE [po_number] = " & Chr(39) & po_number & Chr(39) & ";"

Set rec_set = data_base.OpenRecordset(query)
MsgBox rec_set.Fields("po_ack")
If rec_set.Fields("po_ack") <> Null Then _
    po_ack = True
If rec_set.Fields("po_ack") = Null Then _
    po_ack = False
```

Now, this is supposed to return true, but it returns false?  When I msgbox the record set value, I get "11/12/2012", but when I msgbox the return of the function, it is false?

po_ack stores a Date value, and the value of this particular one is "11/12/2012", so why when I check it against null, it says that "11/12/2012" == null?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null is never equal to anything, not even another Null.

Null is never not equal to anything, not even another Null.

Use the `IsNull()` function to check whether something is Null.

```
If IsNull(rec_set!po_ack) = False Then
    po_ack = True
Else
    po_ack = False
End If
```

See if the `IsDate()` function could be useful for what you want to do.  Here are some sample expressions copied from the Immediate window.

```
? IsDate(Null)
False
? IsDate(Now())
True
? IsDate("2012-11-12")
True
? IsDate("No way, dood")
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Sir I think you should take a look at the links listed below. There is a huge difference between `NULL`, `Nothing` and a blank value in VB. `Null` is something unknown, so it is not equal to `1`, `TRUE`, `""` or anything else. Never compare a variable with null because it results in incorrect logic. Check if you are confusing these types.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/learn-the-differences-between-is-null-and-isnull-in-access/5034252

http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Common-Errors-with-Null

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3710